# reading input from URL in java and sorting values

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am having some trouble find a solution to a problem. I have already did a search to see if I could find the answer, and I did not find anything that help me understand the problem clearer. I think I am missing a part of key point in using wrappers.

Here is the problem: I need to use the URL class to read input from the site below.

[national weather service](http://www.erh.noaa.gov/box/displayF6.php?Month=11&Year=13&Location=PYM)

Once I read it in I need to find the minimum temperature and the day. The temperature and the day will be variables and I must use `ArrayList` to collect and store them. I understand the individual parts that I need to use `ArrayList`, `Scanner` and `Exception` except URL. When I read the URL how do I extract just the values I need?

Should I read the input to a file? I feel I will still be back at square one. Trying to separate the column of days and temperate from everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a few things.

First you don't read a URL, well not in the sense I think you mean.  You can send a HTTP request to a URL and from which you'll hopefully get a response.  Unfortunately [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) will not send HTTP request or process HTTP responses.  To send a HTTP request (get a response and handle all the idiosyncrasies of HTTP) you should look at an API like [Apache's HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/).

From the URL you sight, you'll get a response that contains HTML (at least that's what my browser gets).  You may as well keep it in memory as you're going to need it there to parse it.

Now it's the parsing response that's going to be the hardest bit.  The data appears to have been formatted for dispay using a [monospace font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), ie: it'll display as nice neat columns.  Depending on how complicated you want to make the parsing, you could use this consistent column spacing in an algorthm that:

- identifies the start of the data within the response string (search for the 2nd row of `=`)
- iterate over each line after the start copying the values at columns 10 and 11 adding them to your list until you reach the end of the data (marked by another row of `=`).

Job done.

Comment: thanks. I had search some more and found that I had to parse the Http.